# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'required'

Tags: python, django, forms, required

For some reason, Django is not letting pass the parameter `required=False` to my form fields.

This is my form:

```
class InstrumentSearch(forms.ModelForm): 
    groups = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, required=False)
    time = forms.TimeInput(required=False)
    date = forms.DateField(required=False)
    notes = forms.TextInput(required=False)
```

The error is on the line

```
time = forms.TimeInput(required=False)
```

According to the [Django Documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#required), this should absolutely work.

Comment: `TimeInput` is an ancestor of `Widget`, not `Field` as you expect. You're gonna have the same problem with `TextInput` - it's a widget as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like [TimeInput](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#timeinput) inherits from [Widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget) (via TextInput), which accepts attributes in one dictionary as the `attrs` argument. The examples with TextInput show use of required:

```
>>> name = forms.TextInput(attrs={'required': False})
```

By contrast, Field subclasses such as TimeField and CharField do accept keyword arguments like you use.

Comment: This is not the answer. You can't use widgets at the top level: they need to be part of a Field.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `required`, try using `blank` instead. `blank=False` means it's not required.

```
time = forms.TimeInput(blank=True)
```